# Show the best score a user has had

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got reporting of a user's score every time it happens. Now I want to show the best score a user has had. The table set up is like this:

> Player(id, name)
>
> PlayerHasAchievement(id, playerId,
> achievementId)
>
> Achievement(id, type, amount, time)

This is what I have right now:

```
SELECT MAX(ach.amount) as amount, p.username, ach.time
FROM  achievement as ach
INNER JOIN playerHasAchievement as playAch ON ach.id = playAch.id
INNER JOIN player as p ON p.userId = playAch.userid
WHERE ach.type = 2
GROUP BY amount
ORDER by `amount` DESC
LIMIT $amount
```

I tried to select it distinctly but it didn't work.

Comment: A player's score is the "amount" field in the Achievement table?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the the `ach.time` you are getting is not the same row as the `MAX(amount)`. Join another subquery to get the `MAX(amount)` first.

Note: In the table definitions you posted, `playerHasAchievement` has a field `playerId` not `userId`

```
SELECT MAX(ach.amount) as amount, p.username, MAX(ach.time) MaxTime
FROM  achievement as ach
  INNER JOIN playerHasAchievement as playAch ON ach.id = playAch.id
  INNER JOIN player as p ON p.userId = playAch.playerId
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT playAch.playerId, MAX(ach.amount) as MaxAmount
    FROM  achievement as ach
      INNER JOIN playerHasAchievement as playAch ON ach.id = playAch.id
    WHERE ach.type = 2
    GROUP BY playAch.playerId
  ) g ON p.playerId = g.playerId AND ach.amount = g.MaxAmount
WHERE ach.type = 2
GROUP BY p.playerId
ORDER by `amount` DESC
LIMIT $amount";
```

The reason why we group the outer query, is to avoid ties - say a player had the same score twice.

Answer (score 2):

In your join on line 3 don't you really want

```
INNER JOIN playerHasAchievement as playAch ON ach.id = playAch.achievementId
```

and others are correct, you need to group by your non aggregate columns, not the aggregate one.

Assuming your db layout is as specified in the question here is the query I would use.

```
SELECT ach.amount, p.Name, ach.time
  FROM achievement as ach
   JOIN playerHasAchievement as playAch ON ach.id=playAch.achievementId
   JOIN player AS p ON p.id = playAch.playerId
 WHERE ach.type = 2
   AND ach.amount = (SELECT MAX(ach.amount)
                     FROM achievement as ach
                     JOIN playerHasAchievement as playAch ON ach.id=playAch.achievementId
                     JOIN player AS p ON p.id = playAch.playerId
                     WHERE ach.type = 2)
 GROUP BY ach.amount
 ORDER by ach.time
```

taking the first result (in case there are multiples of the same score) will give you the high score and the lowest time.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You are not using group by appropriately, as you are only grouping by amount.
What about the user name and the time?